# Apsis suffix for object orbiting an exoplanet

Tags: orbit, trajectory, terminology, exoplanet

Is there already an agreed upon apsis suffix for an object orbiting an exoplanet? I don't think it's super likely that there is, as I don't think any moons have been discovered (or at least not at a high certainty) around exoplanets yet. However I am still curious if there is a name, and if not, what it should be.

Comment: The apo- and peri- prefixes followed by a star- or planet-specific suffix dates back to a quaint era when only four objects in the entire universe were known to have smaller objects orbiting them. Now it is just tedious. The same goes for the -ology and -ography suffixes, prefixed by a planet-specific prefix. More and more scientists are writing of the geology of Mars, the geography of Pluto, et cetera. With regard to the apses, the terms periapsis and apoapsis are generic terms. Use them.

Answer (score 3):

Periapsis and apoapsis are the terms used in the [paper](http://dx.doi.org/10.3847/0004-637X/833/1/7) "Global instability of the exo-moon system triggered by photo-evaporation" by Ming Yang et al., *The Astrophysical Journal,* 833:7, 2016.

Comment: Yeah I was guessing it would likely be mostly just the general case until there is enough discussion to warrant more specificity.

Comment: There's the IAU who takes great pride in agreeing upon what to call things, though there's that "Pluto thing" and uncertainty about comets vs asteroids. Perhaps they have a definition? ([Do astronomers generally agree that the distinction between comets and astroids is not so clear?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/19963/7982))

Comment: If which star the planet in question orbits changes how we describe its moon's behavior, that way lies madness^H^H^H^H^H^H^Hepicycles.